# Images source unknown wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Image source is coming unknown in wordpress website.

I can see the items in the Media, but not in the website itself.
I am using Uncode plugin.
And no, I have not migrated my server.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Initial thought leads me to believe you're missing a php extension like imagick, or whatever handles the thumbnail generation. So the only available options are the default sizes that were generated on the previous install when the image got uploaded?

Might be off, but that's what I'd look at first. Make sure you've got all appropriate extensions enabled for the cPanel account.

Comment: What are the errors in your console saying? Might be a clue there?

Comment: https://imgur.com/EcUaNeo   @Paul

Comment: @NarendraSolanki will check and get back to u

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today. Turned out it was a problem coming from the **Custom Field**. I had to go into the custom field, find the image property & change its *preview size* to 'Full Size' (Default is 'Medium(300x300)'). That made the images appear again. Also make sure you haven't set any restrictions with minimum, maximum size, file extension types. It's all inside the custom fields.

[image]